# in Scala how do you join 2 RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have 2 RDD defined as :

```
Sample(Key1,EventDate,Value1) 
Sample2(Key1,ExecutionDate, Label1)
```

I would like to join the two RDD so that I can determine if Key1 exists in Sample2 and then separate the full result into 2 new RDDs : 1 contain ones that Key1 exists in Sample2, the other one would have all Key1 where it does not exists in Sample2

```
FoundKey1(Key1, EventDate,Value1) 
NotFoundKey1(Key1, ExecutionDate,Label1)
```

Essentially I want to get something like this which I do in SQL:

```
 Select Sample.Key1, Sample.EventDate. Key1.Value
 from Sample
 where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Sample2 where Sample2.Key1 = Sample.Key1)
```

And for the other table

```
 SELECT Sample.Key1, Sample.EventDate, Sample.Value1
 from Sample right join Sample2
 on (Sample.Key1 = Sample2.Key2);
```

Sample RDD Values:

```
  Sample(1, 2016-01-05, 10)
  Sample(1, 2016-01-05, 10)
  Sample(2, 2016-01-05, 10)
  Sample(2, 2016-01-05, 10)
  Sample(3, 2016-01-05, 10)

  Sample(1, 2016-01-05, A)
  Sample(3, 2016-01-05, A)
  Sample(5, 2016-01-05, B)
  Sample(6, 2016-01-05, C)
  Sample(7, 2016-01-05, C)
```

Before I forget, my RDD is defined as RDD[Iterable[TestData]] and TestData is a class with the value(Key1,EventDate,Value) for Sample and TestData2 = (Key1,ExecutionDate,Label)

here is what I have tried so far:

```
  val grpSample.groupBy(_.Key1).map(_._2)
  val grpSample2.groupBy(_.Key2).map(_._2)
  val interSect = grpSample.intersection.grpSample2
```

I run this code to see if I am grouping it and I get an error

Comment: show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: The best will to convert them in DataFrame i.e. spark sql then directly call join method based on your condition

Comment: @Akashi.. kinda new to Spark.. so when you say convert to DataFrame how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val rdd1=sample.groupBy(_.Key1)
val rdd2=sample2.groupBy(_.key1)

//to get data for which key exists in both rdd
val result1= rdd1 join rdd2 map (_._2)

//to get data for which key exists in first but not in second rdd
val tempresult= rdd1 fullOuterJoin rdd2
val result2= tempresult filter(_._2._2.isEmpty) map (_._2._1.get)
```

Comment: how do I able to convert the result which became an result1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Iterable[TestData]] = MapPartitionsRDD[47] at map at <console>:58
tempresult: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Option[Iterable[TesData]], Option[Iterable[TestDat2]]))] = MapPartitionsRDD[50] at fullOuterJoin at <console>:57
result2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Option[Iterable[TestData]]] = MapPartitionsRDD[52] at map at <console>:59  so I can access the original (Key1,EventDate,Value)

Comment: try, result2= tempresult filter(_._2._2.isEmpty) map (_._2._1.get)

Comment: Do you find the solution helpful?